# error using "webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iframe, webbrowser-control

When using the following line of code to try to access a link in an iFrame in a webBrowser Control...

```
string Punch = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames("ContentFrame").Document.GetElementById("btnPunch");
```

I receive the following error with the red squiggly line under the word "Frames".

Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlWindow.Frames' cannot be used like a method.

Google is not my friend today...

Added the following...

I have made the following changes and found that I am locating the frame but not the element...

```
        HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["ContentFrame"].Document.GetElementById("btnPunch");

        if (webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No frame found");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Frame found");
        }

        if (elem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("elem is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("elem is not empty");
        }
```

If I can get this to find the element I am trying to click, I will add

```
.InvokeMember("click");
```

To the end to activate the link...

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms.HtmlWindow.Frames` is a property of type `HtmlWindowCollection`.  You can get the desired frame like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["ContentFrame"]
```

Because you are using parentheses rather than square brackets, the compiler thinks you're trying to call a method named `Frames` on the `Window` object.

Comment: I tried it that way as well.  Now I get the following error...  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement' to 'string'

Comment: That's because your expression (what's on the right side of the "=" sign) evaluates to a `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement`, but you are trying to assign it to a variable of type `string` (your variable "Punch").  Maybe you want `GetElementById("btnPunch").InnerText`?  (Additionally, you should probably be doing null checking, unless you know the document will always have the exact structure you expect.)

Comment: I don't know that innerText is what I am looking for.  I have used innerHtml in other locations in my code with great success clicking on links.  But this one is in an iFrame and giving me a headache.  I have added more information to the OP.  Things that I have tried based on our conversation.  I hope it helps.